# Can't comment the original post

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

I can't comment the original post (red rectangle) and I don't know why.

I can comment the other ones.

What I can't do:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: You can comment everywhere only if you have 50+ reputation. Else you can only comment on your posts or if you are the asker of the post

Comment: Cool.. so i can't ask for clarifications.. and i win a thumb down.. cool community here...

Comment: You make it sound like it's the end of the world for you. Stack Overflow is centered on answering questions, not asking for clarifications. And http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @e1che Not yet, no. 50 reputation shouldn't take too long to obtain if you post some good questions or answers, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Seems like he's got 11 answers with 1 downvote. 50 rep looks a bit far.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn you're right, but sometimes clarifications are needed.. =)

Comment: And other times they're not - that's an opportunity for you to actually try to answer the question.

Comment: @Antony Well, I did specify that they had to be *good* questions or answers; looks like he's gained one upvote now at least, so he's 1/5th of the way there.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn thank you i'll try ;)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, support questions shouldn't be downvoted (unless they're complete junk/vandalism).  It's a bad hole in the Meta system, that we punish new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/158761

### Who can post comments?

> All users may leave comments on their own posts and any answers given
>   to their own questions. **Users with at least 50 reputation may comment
>   on any post**. (There is no reputation requirement to post comments on
>   MSO.)

Since your [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2207186/e1che) don't have 50 reputation, you can't, for now. But getting 50 reputation on Stackoverflow is not so hard ;)

And don't worry about downvotes. Because [upvotes and downvotes different on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).