# Bug when flagging a comment that has since been edited

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

When I clicked the flag button on a comment, a popup of the entire page for *page not found* appeared (see image below). I think that this behaviour should be fixed as it is a rather confusing experience. The comment must have just been edited as I clicked the flag button.

Also, why did the popup say *page not found*?

[image: Image of bug screen capture]

Comment: [I think this is relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com)...kind of...

Comment: Yes, the red does not look great there :)

Comment: The comment was most likely *deleted*, not edited. The popup is loading a page, e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/popup/flag/524663 so when the comment with that ID is deleted you'll indeed get "Page Not Found" pop up.

Comment: The comment is most definitely still there. See the 4th one here with the edit icon next to it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175138/cant-comment-the-original-post

Comment: Since I can't flag my own comment can't reproduce it as I wanted... anyway you sure that's the comment you tried to flag? When you try to flag now is it working fine?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm sure yes. If you look at the minute difference between his comment and Antony's, the time difference is the same for that edited one and Antony's now. Flagging it now works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: YO DAWG]

Seriously though, fixed in the next build with a proper error message.